# Poweshell Function Execution gives false output

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I have two functions in my powershell script

**check_python** which checks if python exists in my computer

**is_git_repo** which checks the current working dir in git repository

I have problem executing this powershell script

```
$REMOTE_URL = git config --get remote.origin.url

Function check_python{
    $python_version = python --version
    $python_version
    if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ){
        write-host ("Python is installed with version $python_version")
    }else {
        write-host ("Kindly install python")
        exit 1
    }
}

Function is_git_repo {
    $REMOTE_URL >$null
    if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ){
        write-host ("Running in git repo")
    } else{
        write-host ("It's not a Git repo")
        exit 1
    }
}

check_python
is_git_repo
```

Executing the above powershell script in non git repo gives me ***Running in git repo*** output, Ideally executing is_git_repo function in a non git repo should return ***exit code 1*** but it doesn't

But when I comment out the **check_python** function it gives me the correct output, I don't know what's this weird behavior.

Comment: Hint: Only the `python --version` command is executed inside a function. The other function `Function is_git_repo` doesn't execute `git` at all.

Comment: Yeah @vonPryz I get that, But ideally that shouldn't be the case right ?? because when I run only the `is_git_repo function`, It works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the script above the git command will run immediately, setting the lastexitcode before you run your functions. The output of your command will be the value of the variable. So, `$REMOTE_URL >$null` will just redirect your previously generated output to null, which will always be successful.

You should either move the command inside of the function or change the if to evaluate your variable.

Try something like this:

```
Function check_python{
    $python_version = python --version
    $python_version
    if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ){
        write-host ("Python is installed with version $python_version")
    }else {
        write-host ("Kindly install python")
        exit 1
    }
}

Function is_git_repo {
    $REMOTE_URL = git config --get remote.origin.url
    if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ){
        write-host ("Running in git repo")
    } else{
        write-host ("It's not a Git repo")
        exit 1
    }
}

check_python
is_git_repo
```

Comment: Hey It works now. I got the Idea of how it's working. Thankss man

Answer (score 0):

```
Function check_python{
    $python_version = python --version
    $python_version
    if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ){
        write-host ("Python is installed with version $python_version")
    }else {
        write-host ("Kindly install python")
        exit 1
    }
}

Function is_git_repo{
    $result = .\git config --get remote.origin.url 
    
    if ( $result -ne ""){
        write-host ("Running in git repo")
    } else{
        write-host ("It's not a Git repo")
        exit 1
    }
}
is_git_repo
check_python
```

also you can use:

```
try{ Start-Process ... -ErrorAction Stop }
catch{exit 1}
```

the script".\git config --get remote.origin.url" will only work if you are in the right directory. That is, you need something like

```
$GitFolderLocation = "c:\git\example"
    Set-Location $GitFolderLocation
    Start-Process \.git -Wait -NoNewWindow -WorkingDirectory $GitFolderLocation -ArgumentList "config --get remote.origin.url"
```

Comment: The script that you have given, I need `check_python function` to run first. It still gives me error. And also my intention is to run the script on absolute directory. Think so I don't need `$GitFolderLocation`. The error raises when I run `check_python` first and `is_git_repo` second.